# Recover .php files from an accidental partition format

Tags: data-recovery

I'm trying to recover .php files from an accidental partition format. I've used a lot of software, but the results are the same, unreadable text that looks:

[image]

[Download full file](https://mega.co.nz/#!hFRDUJaa!ZmJtHBFqloPSiKNt8tH4PlxGlhprBwR-4JrSK_9tpjQ).

Comment: Well, the file may have been encrypted (doubtful), but it appears corrupted. Unless you can recover the original, I think you've lost it (you need to restore from backup or from the live server)

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted the partition, you may be better off recovering the entire partition rather than individual files. This looks like it will do the job http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/, but whether it is really 'free' or not can only be discovered when trying to recover the partition. I have used a very good command line based one before but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: http://www.piriform.com/recuva is 100% free.  If Recuva can't recover the file it means the file is corrupt and/or incomplete.